# Mono vs .NET - difference in server certificate validation?

Tags: c#, ssl, xamarin, mono, tls1.2

I have the following code:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

        HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.badssl.com/").GetResponse();
        HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("https://wrong.host.badssl.com/").GetResponse();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebRequest) sender).RequestUri + " " + sslPolicyErrors); 

        return true;
    }
}
```

I run it on Windows 8 and Mac OSX.

Mac OS X

```
https://www.badssl.com/ None
https://www.badssl.com/ None
https://wrong.host.badssl.com/ RemoteCertificateChainErrors
```

Windows (.net 4.5):

```
https://www.badssl.com/ None
https://www.badssl.com/ None
https://wrong.host.badssl.com/ RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
```

Any idea on why I get different results? I would like to have `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` on the Mac OS X case as well since I think that it is correct.

Comment: Have you tried running it on Mono on Windows? Might be worth a shot

Comment: I would scroll through the Mono source as it appears they are using native OS-X functions to derive the cert issue ... `EvaluateSystem` `CheckUsage` etc... `https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/5a701f39c7d914c5a04da2d33f806b0709b67a5a/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/SystemCertificateValidator.cs

Comment: Tested on Mono on windows and there I get RemoteCertificateNameMismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Mono has its own implementation of a TLS stack. .NET uses the native Windows stack (SChannel). Both stacks differ a lot in behavior and capabilities (like no TLS 1.2 with Mono). Apart from that the error in Mono might come from different root CA, i.e. Mono will not find a path to a trusted root CA and complain early before even checking the name while .NET finds the trusted path and complains later when validating the subject of the certificate against the URL.

Comment: I tried to isolate the problem with root CA issues by first validating https://www.badssl.com/ and that that worked out good.

Comment: FYI: Mono does have 1.2 support if you use the new TLS provider... http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-s-new-TLS-provider-td4666825.html

Comment: @SushiHangover: Sure you can use a stack which is not officially released yet (i.e. not included into a release of Mono) and which contains the explicit disclaimer: [NOT BEEN SECURITY AUDITED AND NO GUARANTEE ABOUT SECURITY OR STABILITY](https://github.com/mono/mono-tls).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If you use that "testing" provider, fully understand... but I like many others use the native OS providers.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I find now information that such native providers already exist. The link contains only an intention to implement such providers someday in the future.